# Strange JSON parsing bug of jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2, the follow picture is the strange problem I found in jQuery (screenshot from my chrome):

[image]

Please notice the highlight position. This is so strange, the jQuery function `parseJSON` change the "picture_id" field. Why?

Comment: I'm guessing it's some overflow problem?

Comment: It's not an overflow problem. It's a floating point precision problem

Comment: @trex279, maybe, when I change the id to string, the parsing result is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is too large to fit in a 32 bit integer, so it is stored in a floating point variable. The precision of floating point values is insufficient to store all significant digits in the value in your JSON object.

A good explanation of the floating-point precision "problem" can be found here:

http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: maybe I should change the data type to string?

Comment: That would help. You probably don't need the actual numeric value of the id anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your number is just to big so it is rounded down to the highest possible number.

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Try to use it as string. You could use this [BigInt library](http://leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html).